# Deploy a Ghost site to a bare remote git repo

Tags: git, gruntjs, ghost

I have a bare repo on my server that I'm attempting to push a local Ghost site to.

On the server, the Ghost `grunt init` is unable to successfully complete because there is no working tree:

```
$ grunt init

Running "update_submodules:default" (update_submodules) task
Warning: fatal: /usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree. Use --force to continue.
```

I suspect that a way around this would be to do all `grunt` work locally, and avoid `gitignore`ing the results of the build. If so, can anyone offer some insight on what to remove from the Ghost `gitignore`?

My preference would be to run `grunt` on the server after pushing. Is there any way to make that possible for a bare repo?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I was thinking of this sort of backwards. I was trying to push a local repo to a bare git repo on the server, but...

**The preferred method is to install a Ghost build directly on the server.**

Example:

```
$ sudo wget https://ghost.org/zip/ghost-latest.zip
```

From there you would unzip and perform the standard setup commands.

---

[Digital Ocean has a great guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-blog-with-ghost-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) that shows you how to:

1. Install a Ghost build directly to Ubuntu
2. Edit the Ghost config file
3. Proxy with Nginx
4. Fire up the blog server permanently with modules like `forever` and `pm2`

[I wrote a post on the Ghost blog I was able to set up as a result, providing a few more details](http://blog.ashryan.io/setting-up-ghost-on-digital-ocean-and-ubuntu/).